# Rearrange single lines to form closed polygon?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry, boost-polygon

assumed I have a rectangle:

```
A------B
|      |
|      |
D------C
```

Normally this rectangle is formed by an array of coordinates A-B-C-D-A which describe a closed polygon.

Now I do not have such an array but a bunch of separate lines B-A, D-A, B-C-D. When drawing both, the result is always the same rectangle but in second case much more data are used for it. So I want to rearrange and optimise the second case in order to get one single array of coordinates as in first case.

My question: is this possible somehow with boost::geometry or boost::polygon? If yes, how can this be done? If no: any other possibilities?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the end points of the lines identical or just approximate?

Comment: @AlanBirtles they are identical

Comment: should be fairly simple then to find points at the end of one line that match the point at the end of another and combine them together?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, for sure, I can invent the wheel again - but why should I do that when there is a library out there doing that job already? Btw: it is not that simple, it is not only simple sorting and rearranging, some lines need to be reversed (B-A in my example above)

Comment: Will the number of lines always be 4? Is the desired result always a convex polygon, or could it be a concave one too? Or maybe it will always be a rectangle?

Comment: @schteppe no, the number of lines is variables as well as the number of already connected lines. It can be any type and shape of polygon, but none where lines cross each other

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no algorithm for this in Boost.Geometry.

However there are things that might help you with writing your own:

- `boost::geometry::equals()` - check if a point is equal to another one, this is done WRT machine epsilon so you may consider using your own version strictly comparing coordinates
- `boost::geometry::intersects()` - check if a linestring intersects some other one
- `boost::geometry::index::rtree<>` - speed up the searching process

  - store the endpoints with the ids of the linestrings and search for equal points
  - store bounding boxes of linestrings and search for the corresponding linestrings
- `boost::geometry::envelope()` - calculate a bounding box of a linestring
- `boost::geometry::correct()` - check the orientation of a polygon/ring and reverse to match the type definition
- `boost::geometry::is_valid()` - verify if the polygon/ring is valid (e.g. the edges don't cross other edges)